# DataGridViewTextBoxCell multi-line editing using button

Tags: c#, multiline, datagridviewtextboxcell

How to do the multi-line editing for non-multi-line `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` like the text property in a Visual Studio project?

the multi-line editing should appear after clicking the dropdown-like button, but `textboxcell` should display only the first line.

I still can't post a picture so here's a [link of the picture](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/windows/propwnd/sections1.gif) that shows a text property with a dropdown-like `button` for multi-line editing..hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I don't really know how to start for an  attempt that would give the exact answer I really want. As a remedy(temporary) I added a control to datagridview(a button) that pops-up a window that has multi-line textbox control that will be used for editing then passing the value back to the datagrid view..that works, but not exactly the way I wanted..if any, I would like to imitate the exact functionality of text property in visual studio. I dont really know how.